# Is there a way to mark as "new" for a Div when it is just generated, and change the flag after it's been touched?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, angular8

I am using Angular 8 to generate content-editable Divs(drag-able) thru a button, and I'd like to have an indicator to mark the `new` generated ones before they are touched, so that I can apply some logic accordingly.

And when the new ones has been touched, the `new` indicator should be removed.

Is there a way to do so?

The generated Div is like below:

```
<div  id="div_id"  cdkDrag >
    <div (focusout)="blur()" class="contentContainer" [contentEditable]="isDragDisable" >
        {{content}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible using JS

```
$('#div_id').html(data);
```

data is the new text
then to change the status when clicked, find the code below

```
$("#div_id").click(function() {
    $("#div_id").html("");
```

}